# C# DataGridView Binding to table inop

Tags: datagridview, binding

Trying to display table data in a data grid view.  Have followed many blog suggestions with no resolution.  Have reduced the code down to the simple test case below but grid view remains blank.  Last check grid view Rows = 0. (not verified again for this exact code but still blank).

```
    private void ImportTable(string fileName)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Column 1", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Column 2", typeof(int));
        table.Rows.Add(1, 2);

        dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

        BindingSource SBind = new BindingSource();
        SBind.DataSource = table;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = SBind;
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: Why is the code creating a “New” `DataGridView` with the code… `dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();` … ? … what happens if you comment out that line of code? I am just saying that it “appears” `dataGridView1` already exist and there is no need to create a new one.

Comment: Appreciate the help... you are correct.  This code was creating a new instance of the data grid view and must have applied the data there but it was not visible and my original view remained empty.  Commented it out and data went correctly to the GUI.